# Comparison between opengl and directX

Tags: opengl, directx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL or DirectX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240625/opengl-or-directx)

Not want to trigger war, but really want to know pros and cons of those two mainstream graphic library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest the hard part is not the API, it's the higher level 3d stuff. Below that both APIs have vertex buffers, index bufers, textures, shaders, and so on and although they express that in different ways it's the concepts that are the hard part not the API. If you understand d3d11 then you'll pick up opengl in no time and vice-versa.

Practical considerations are that opengl is available on more platforms, but that d3d tends to be better supported and work better on windows platforms. d3d has a more object oriented interface whereas opengl has a strictly "c" style interface (Although it deals internally with objects through "names" and handles). This likely makes opengl easier to start learning than d3d11 which needs quite a bit of setup - but in "real" applications there won't be much in it.

d3d11 is designed to work better on multi core cpus and mult threaded software. This adds some complexity to using it, but allows you to perhaps take more advantage of the hardware then opengl might at this point in time. (However if you are still at the stage of asking which to use then it's very unlikely to matter to you!)

it tends to be much easier to find documentation for d3d9 than opengl (I mean for "modern" stuff, not examples using obsolete ways of doing things, (which is a problem with opengl, a lot of the tutorials and code out there is frankly obsolete and doesn't really use opengl properly now). Whereas it's quite hard to find good d3d11 examples and tutorials still.

If you've not used either I would very much recommend learning the basics of BOTH and the slightly different approaches to the same underlying functionallity. Don't get caught up in saying one is better than the other, learn both and see which seems a better fit. This is what most people do, unfortunatly most of the "advice" you'll get on the internet seems be to from someone who has decided that pushing one or the other API is important to them!

I found it a useful excercise when learning to abstract out the differences with a small c++ framework that creates textures, vertex buffers, index buffers, renderstate collections etc, and implements those concepts in terms of BOTH apis/.

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL is a cross-platform API for 3D graphics. DirectX is a restricted-platform API for graphics, audio, music, device input, networking, and more.

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all, DirectX is a lot more than 3D accelerated rendering.  I assume you are talking about Direct3D.

Anyway, here's my completely biased opinion:

- Direct3D runs on Windows, Xbox, and *sometimes* Wine (depending on the particular application/game).  Choosing Direct3D ties your product heavily to Microsoft platforms.
- Coding in Direct3D (at least the last time I tried it, which was some years ago) makes rolling around naked in honey, walking up to a hornet's nest, and beating the tar out of it sound like a pleasant afternoon.
- OpenGL runs on almost every platform imaginable and supports most of the same stuff that Direct3D does in immediate mode.
- The OpenGL API is mostly clean and a joy to code against.

Comment: There is no immediate mode anymore in DirectX, it must've been a long time ago that you tried directx!

Comment: I thought it was retained mode that they did away with, since nobody used it.

Comment: One might reasonably assume that, since people *do* still code against Direct3D, programmers are generally rational human beings, and I've not heard of any honey-hornet related incidents, there are some advantages to be had.

Comment: @ijw: I did say I was biased. ;) But I've never met a Direct3D coder who really enjoys coding with it. Then again, I haven't met many Direct3D coders.

Comment: @cdhowie: so then the advantage is 'my PHB pays me if I code in DirectX and not if I code in OpenGL' ;)  But seriously, I was thinking along the lines of 'OpenGL support sucks on some hardware', which I always assumed was the reason.

Comment: To be honest I fond d3d a _much_ nicer api, it's a reasonably well designed object oriented set of objects to work with that cover all the functionality whereas opengl is hundreds and hundreds of stand alone functions, and must of the functionallity has been bolted on as "extensions" rather than being in the original design. Don't get me wrong, I think opengl is fine - but I find it hard to believe anyone could describe it as "clean" when compared with dx11

Comment: @ijw I'm not really sure either. If hardware support is the issue, I'm not sure why Neverwinter Nights was coded with OpenGL, nor why WoW has (or had, it's been some years since I've played that either) an OpenGL backend that worked flawlessly with Wine.

Comment: @cdhowie: WoW has an OpenGL backend to support macs.

Comment: The OpenGL ES 2.0 spec, which is a consolidated subset of the desktop spec erasing all of the legacy stuff in favour of a fully programmable, GPU friendly pipeline, exposes a grand total of 109 functions. Hardly hundreds and hundreds. I seriously doubt D3D contains substantially fewer methods.